# AngularJS component relationship with each other

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to understand the hierarchy of all components in AngularJS. How they are related to each other? Is there any graphical representation to understand that?

Comment: Here I just want to understand hierarchy of all components. We can create controller using module.controller and define it ther and also we can write controller in directive and state etc. So its getting very much confusing to understand which is parent and which is child and what contains what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)

> Extends the Developer Tools, adding tools for debugging and profiling AngularJS applications.

[image: models]
[image: deps]

[gitHub](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang)

Comment: This is very good tool, but still I am looking for something very Generic thing at architectural level. But Thanks for this answer

Comment: I am confused woth Controller and controller in directive as we write code. Are they different or its just different ways to write code.